# Display a table from a website

Tags: bash, grep, osx, curl, html

I have an idea for what I want to do, but am not sure exactly what to do. I want to `curl http://www.bostonglobe.com/sports/tvradio/listings` then somehow display a table on this page. The table is `<table class="nextgame">`. I am not sure if this is possible, but if it is I would like to write a function to my `bash_profile` (I am on mac) that will simply display this table in my terminal whenever it is called.

Maybe somehow I should try to use html2text?

Thank you.

Comment: Using something designed for terminals might be easier:
http://panz.io/mlbgame/

Comment: I see no table in the page. A good task for [tag:puppeteer]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the table in question is generated by javascript, and the info you want doesn't appear in the HTML. This precludes simple wget- or curl-based solutions. You could try using something like PhantomJS to get the contents in a headless setting, but you're probably better off trying to use the library @datUser mentioned.